# Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues in Graph Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I am teaching myself some basics about graph theory, and I fell upon the idea that there exists eigenvectors and eigenvalues for graphs. Could you please explain what the significance of this is? I understand what eigenvectors and eigenvalues are. However, I am having a hard time understanding how they relate to graph theory since there are no vectors in graphs. I was thinking maybe the  adjacency matrix has to do with this. If use the det(lambda*i-A)=0 where A is the adjacency matrix method to get the eigenvectors. What will these eigenvectors represent in this case? And, what do their corresponding eigenvectors represent?

Comment: Does that answer your questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245232/how-does-graph-fourier-transform-retain-structural-information/4245442#4245442

Comment: And this one too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094370/interpretation-of-the-laplacian-operator-in-graphs/4094475#4094475

Comment: The quickest interpretation is that the adjacency matrix is related to walks, and thus so are the eigenvalues via linear algebraic relations between matrices and their eigenvalues. Of course, this is a whole field of math, so a complete answer would take a collection of books at the minimum.